# How to measure ALL independent variables in ALL AND DIFFERENT combinations influence the dependent variable

Tags: regression

[Different combinations for independent variables: what I need in the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18gmS.png)

[image]

EDIT: How to measure ALL independent variables in ALL and DIFFERENT combinations influence the dependent variable (PLEASE see the above image for what I need to do)

I'm given a large dataset with 6 independent variables and 1 dependent variable.

My goal is to measure how all of the 6 independent variables (all of them in different combinations) influence the dependent variable (like what I put in the image above).

ANOVA / Multiple linear regression analysis / OLS regression doesn't work because it only has 1 independent variable VS. 1 dependent variable.

MNOVA / Turkey HSD post-hoc test doesn't work because it measures 2 independent variables VS. 1 dependent variable.

What can I do to complete this analysis? Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking how to make a model to predict the value of the dependent variable each of the $6 \times 2 \times 5 \times 2 \times 5$ different configurations that you can make using the listed values of the variables  in the table? Or something else?

Comment: It could be the way to solve this problem. What I want to do is how all of these independent variables (in different combinations) are influencing the dependent variable (in this case I haven't included in the image attached here.

Comment: How is that different than multiple regression?